# How to make "view passwords"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, passwords

I'm making password recognition system, and I want to make "View Passwords" function, which can switch hide to show passwords. I have no idea how to make this function.

Here is my brief code:

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

#Entry box to get password from users
getPassword = Entry(root, show='*').pack()
```

I am stuck here.
I don't even know whether I should use Button() or other function such as checkbox to make "View Passwords" function.

Do you have any good idea to fix this?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Teach me how to write the app I want” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: [I’m stuck](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/, without specifics, and without your applicable research, is an issue for a tutor in problem analysis or specification.  It’s not focused enough for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Read the documentation for the `Entry` widget. The answer to your question can be found in the list of available options for the widget.

Comment: I got it. This stack overflow is for not people who just want code they want to make, but people who have specific problem. I'll carefully ask questions next time. Thank you for advises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [universal widget methods](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html) `cget()` and `config()` to get and set the current `show` option of your `Entry` widgets to define a function to toggle the display of contents of the `Entry` widget(s).
You can then make the function the call-back `command` of a `Button`. You could also use it with `Radiobutton` or `ttk.Checkbutton` widgets in a similar manner.

Here's a runnable example to illustrate what I'm saying:

```
import tkinter as tk

HIDE_CHAR = '*'

def toggle_password_display():
    show = HIDE_CHAR if not password_entry.cget('show') else ''
    password_entry.config(show=show)

root = tk.Tk()

# Entry box to get password from users.
password_entry = tk.Entry(root, show=HIDE_CHAR)
password_entry.pack()

toggle_btn = tk.Button(root, text='Toggle password display', command=toggle_password_display)
toggle_btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Before and after clicking the `Button`:

[image: screenshot of code running]

Comment: Would the treeview columns have something similar? To show as password

Comment: @CoolCloud: No, not that I am aware of.

Comment: I'm trying to look up universal widget methods, but I can't find anything, except the link you gave me. Are those universal widget methods special or anything like that?
Also, I can't understand this section

show = HIDE_CHAR if not password_entry.cget('show') else ''

I had never seen this way to use if statement.

Comment: Unfortunately `tkinter` is notorious for being poorly documented, which is why I often refer to the site I did (which is a copy of the original [New Mexico Tech website](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/index.html) that got deleted after the author died). A number of others also exist, but none are what I would call "authoritative". That assignment statement you wonder about is using something called a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions). Also see [PEP 308](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/).

Answer (score -1):

usage

```
    Password_entry.config('*')
```

to make the password invisible
And

```
    Password_entry.config('')
```

to make the password visible

Comment: This was not the functionality they were asking for and does not answer the question